# Change @RequestBody object based on @PathVariable variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hello i am using spring boot 3 and need some help

My controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/data/update/{value}",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> editReg(@PathVariable String value, @Validated @RequestBody EditRequest editEmailBulkRequest){
    
}
```

My first DTO class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EditEmailBulkRequest {
    @NotNull
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
}
```

My second DTO class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EditEmailBulkRequestNew {
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String org;
}
```

Is there any way to judge on the basis of path variable . like if @PathVariable value is 1 then @RequestBody will  **EditEmailBulkRequest** and if @PathVariavle value is 2 the @RequestBody object will become **EditEmailBulkRequestNew** .
Or is there any way to change the DTO class via checking any variable  in same endpoint ??

Comment: You may use `JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation on your request body class, let your request body class consists of all fields, basis on path variable , you may do a nested validation ! Although I would not recommend this approach as API contracts should be consistent and follow all 6 REST principles , but still basis on path variable you may check that if pathVariable value is 2 , you may want to do a non-null check for new request body fields

Comment: I highly recommend you to go through what REST is and what meaning does request and response body has

Comment: Maybe bad, but recommendation is, use custom DTO where you have inside both DTO, then just use -> if == 1 use new dtoCustom.getEditEmailBulkRequest  else if ==2 use new dtoCustom.getEditEmailBulkRequestNew. Maybe that way will be better because your input data not changing, object inside of object will be changed and choose by @PathVariable data